# Does log4j uses NIO for writing data to file?

Tags: java, log4j, nio

It seems to be pretty fast already and i was just wondering if anyone knows if its using NIO. I tried searching the whole source code for NIO (well, its kind of way to search :) lol); but did not hit anything. Also, If its not using NIO; do you think its worthwhile to modify log4j to use NIO also to make it more faster? Any pointers advises and links to some resources would be lot helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, If its not using NIO; do you
>   think its worthwhile to modify of
>   log4j to use NIO also to make it more
>   faster?

No, unless logging is a significant part of your application's activities, in which case there is usually something wrong.

You seem to be under the impression that NIO 'is faster', but this is not true in general. Just try creating two files, one with standard IO and one with NIO, writing a bunch of data to them and closing them. You'll see the performance hardly differs. NIO will only perform better in certain use cases; most usually the case of *many* connections.

Comment: Yes; these are significant part of application in one mode and i want that mode also to be better performing. I am writing from a single application so i am not sure how to associate connections here. May be can i compare it to number of threads trying to write something to log? If so; yes there are lot of threads trying to write something. I know that writing a lot into log from application is not the best solutionl; but i just want to make sure its not the worst :) too. Thanks a lot for insights. I will try comparing IO and NIO myself with some examples.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [FileAppender source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.java?view=markup).  Pretty much just standard `java.io`.

Comment: Thanks for the source. Is it worth to implement a NIO appender equivalent to these ones? Will it make it faster?

Comment: No.  NIO is non-blocking IO as opposed to the one-thread-per-connection model in Java's standard IO.  It's not about speed.

Comment: @stevendick: I was thinking about RandomAccessFile with FileChannel and MBB. Won't it help a little? :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why FileChannel could be any faster than FileOutputStream in this case.

maybe by using MappedByteBuffer? but in append mode, the behavior is OS dependent.

ultimately, the performance depends on your hard drive, your code matters very little.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about MBBs only. Thats why i asked this question itself! Thanks! Will keep these points in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on Confusion's answer, File NIO blocks as well. That's why it is not faster than traditional File IO in **some** scenarios. Quoting [O'Reilly's Java NIO book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002886.do):

> File channels are always blocking and cannot be placed into
>   nonblocking mode. Modern operating systems have sophisticated caching
>   and prefetch algorithms that usually give local disk I/O very low
>   latency. Network filesystems generally have higher latencies but often
>   benefit from the same optimizations. The nonblocking paradigm of
>   stream-oriented I/O doesn't make as much sense for file-oriented
>   operations because of the fundamentally different nature of file I/O.
>   For file I/O, the true winner is asynchronous I/O, which lets a
>   process request one or more I/O operations from the operating system
>   but does not wait for them to complete. The process is notified at a
>   later time that the requested I/O has completed. Asynchronous I/O is
>   an advanced capability not available on many operating systems. It is
>   under consideration as a future NIO enhancement.

Edit: With that said, you can get better read/write efficiency if you use File NIO with a MappedByteBuffer. Note that using MappedByteBuffer in Log4j 2 is under [consideration](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-431).

Comment: Wow very confusing, is this still the case two and a half years later?